# Is there a simple way to play Retropi games online with a friend?

Tags: retropie

I am interested in playing co-op and versus games with friends who are in different locations. The only option I've seen is Netplay (https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Netplay), but I've found that the setup is pretty tricky if you're looking to sneak in a quick game. Are there other options out there? Are there options that will automatically match you with others who want to play?